# $\arccos(r)$ is a unbiased estimator of $\arccos(\rho)$

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics, references, unbiased-estimator

I am looking for a reference of the above fact in the title where $r$ is the usual sample correlation estimate and $\rho$ is the true correlation coefficient. I think the result is valid only for Bivariate normal sample. Is it the case ? Proofs are welcome too.